# Converting a list of ints to a word

Tags: java, string, encoding, integer

I am working on a game, and there is a component to this game that will assign a specific name to a creature depending on its attributes. Specifically, I have a set of ints that tell me which attributes the creature in the game possesses, and I need to formulate a name from these particular attributes.

What I was thinking was: assign a syllable to each number 1-47 (via Hashmap) and this way depending on which attribute the animal has the string would be different. However one obvious flaw is that the string would be way too long. I wrote an algorithm that essentially combines syllables if there are over 4 syllables. However this type of approach creates many similar results especially after around 20 syllables have been shrunk down into 4. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could turn a series of integers into a legible word that is somewhat unique? (Some copies are okay, but for the most part I want a unique word for each combination of numbers)

Comment: Hash functions serve pretty much the same purpose. Try hashing the attributes and then generate the name from the first few bytes, optionally using the first few bits as the number of syllables.

Comment: What's the programming language? Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm turning the list of ints into one 16-bit int using hashcode. And then converting that int into a string by pretending it's a base n number system where n is the number of syllables and each digit is a syllable. (By restricting the int to 16 bits you have fewer syllables). I don't know if that makes sense but I hope the output will satisfy your requirements.

```
    import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class NameGenerator {

    final static List<String> syllables = Arrays.asList("ka", "sa", "ta", "na", "ha", "ma", "ya", "ra", "wa",
            "ki", "si", "ti", "ni", "hi", "mi", "yi", "ri", "wi",
            "ku", "su", "tu", "nu", "hu", "mu", "yu", "ru", "wu",
            "ke", "se", "te", "ne", "he", "me", "ye", "re", "we",
            "ko", "so", "to", "no", "ho", "mo", "yo", "ro", "wo");
    final static int maxSyllable = syllables.size() - 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] attributes = new int[]{25, 325, 4, 2, 11, 98, 23};
        String name = toName(attributes);
        System.out.println("name = " + name);
    }

    public static String toName(int[] attributes) {
        int hashCode = Arrays.hashCode(attributes);
        int smallHashCode = (hashCode >> 16) ^ (hashCode & 0xffff);
        return toName(smallHashCode);
    }

    public static String toName(int i) {
        if (i < 0) {
            i = -i;
        }
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        while (i > maxSyllable) {
            buf.append(syllables.get(i % maxSyllable));
            i = i / maxSyllable;
        }
        buf.append(syllables.get(i));
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I put this code into eclipse and it is great! I love how concise the code is as well, thank you very much for the code!

Comment: I'm delighted to hear it. Thanks for posing such an interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

Represent the "series (list) of integers" with an enum and the set of creature attributes with a [Bitset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html):

```
import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class BitSetString {
    private static Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
    private static Prop[] props = Prop.values(); 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BitSet bs = new BitSet(47) {
            @Override public String toString() {
                Matcher m = regex.matcher(super.toString());
                StringBuffer r = new StringBuffer();
                while (m.find()) m.appendReplacement(r, props[Integer.parseInt(m.group())].toString());
                m.appendTail(r);
                return r.toString();
            }
        };
        bs.set(Prop.ZED.ordinal());
        bs.set(Prop.IFF.ordinal());
        bs.set(Prop.WOW.ordinal());
        bs.set(Prop.HEX.ordinal());
        bs.set(Prop.ALT.ordinal());
        bs.set(Prop.FOO.ordinal());
        System.out.println(bs.toString()); // outputs '{FOO, WOW, IFF, ZED, HEX, ALT}'
    }

    private static enum Prop {
        FOO, BAR, WOW, HEY, CAN, CAR, CUB, BIG, FAT, DRY, WET, EGO, MEH, EYE,
        GOD, GUN, IFF, JOY, KEG, LOG, NIL, OHM, PIG, SAX, SKY, TIC, VIM, VOX,
        YIN, ZED, HEX, HOG, GNU, ELF, CAB, BUS, ABS, ALT, ANY, CUE, DIF, FEZ,
    }
}
```

Benefits:

1. [BitSet#toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toString--) yields the unique word string for a
   combination of creature properties.
2. Predictable order is defined by the enum, regardless of what order
   the properties are added to the creature.
3. Bitset provides convenient set operations and requires less memory than storing integers.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on Java 8 Stream API.
The method return the unique word if each number from integers sequence is lower then syllables arrays length.

```
final static String[] syllables = new String[] {"ka", "sa", "ta", "na", "ha", "ma", "ya", "ra", "wa",
        "ki", "si", "ti", "ni", "hi", "mi", "yi", "ri", "wi",
        "ku", "su", "tu", "nu", "hu", "mu", "yu", "ru", "wu",
        "ke", "se", "te", "ne", "he", "me", "ye", "re", "we",
        "ko", "so", "to", "no", "ho", "mo", "yo", "ro", "wo"};

public static String listToString(List<Integer> list) {
    return list.stream().map(num -> syllables[num % syllables.length])
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will look into this aswell!

Comment: @Radiodef I've modify my answer. Result word should be unique if each number from sequence is lower then length of syllables array.